# Get textAttachment in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an NSTextAttachment. I need to have some identifier attached to it, so I did this:

```
textAttachment.setValue(id, forKey: idKey)
```

In `shouldChangeTextIn range`, I have:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
   if text.isEmpty && textView.textStorage.containsAttachments(in: range) {
       // retrieve textAttachment
   }
   return true
}
```

I want to retrieve the `textAttachment` and its id if the user deletes it (by pressing the backspace button on the keyboard).

How can I get the `textAttachment` in a UITextView given the range it is in?